# Error al seleccionar Checkbox

Tags: javascript, typescript, checkbox

Tengo el siguiente código (muy sencillo)

```
    if (document.getElementById(id).checked == false) 
document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
```

Y funciona perfectamente, pero muestra el siguiente error

[image: Error mostrado]

Como he dicho antes, funciona. Pero necesito eliminar dicho error para compilar la primera vez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que castear/convertir el resultado de `getElementById` a `HTMLInputElement` para poder acceder a la propiedad `checked`:

```
var checkbox = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id);
if(!checkbox.checked)
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Perfecto. Funciona

Answer (score 0):

Deberías utilizar mejor `hasAttribute('checked')` para comprobar si está marcado y `setAttribute('checked', true)'  para marcarlo:

```js
function check(){
  if (!document.getElementById('myCheck').hasAttribute('checked')) 
    document.getElementById('myCheck').setAttribute('checked' ,true);
}

document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', check);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">

<button id="check">Check</button>
```

Referencia:

[checked - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/checked)